# How to use SPAN_USER

Tags: android, html, text, android-edittext

I want to add extra information on a specific span for my text, for what I´ve seen I could use SPAN_USER, but there seems to be no example on how to use them, what is the proper way to use them?

Comment: Its a Static final int, you just use it `Spannable.SPAN_USER`

Comment: but can I add a string to that span as extra information?

Comment: um no, its an `int` so its a flag, you can use it as a conditional

Comment: ohh ok... make that as an answer since that´s what I wanted to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPAN_USER` its a `Static final int` value, you can use it like this `Spannable.SPAN_USER`, its a `flag` that can be used as a conditional.
A string cant be add to it.